# Can domain administrator access local administrator data?

Tags: active-directory, windows-10

If a PC is added to Active Directory, but I log in as local admin `LA`.
Would any **Domain Administrator** be able to access any local admin `LA` data? (such as user folder or revealing Chrome Stored Passwords)?

I tried revealing a chrome password using the domain user `DU` (That has admin rights on the PC) but Windows refused it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the "Domain Administrators" group is added to the local "Administrators" group of a computer, when you join it to the domain. Unless it was removed or changed, the domain admin can access anything on the local computer.

Chrome encrypts stored passwords, and probably with a key derived from the user account it was stored with. That would explain why you can't access the passwords.

Comment: `ChromePass` can be used to just show passwords stored by chrome.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. The question now is: as a local admin, can I remove the "Domain Administrators" group added to the local "Administrators" group?

Comment: You can. But talk to your sysadmins before you do, because that will probably be something they don't like.